# Picking numbers for chores - Probability

Tags: probability

We do numbers to decide who has to do a chore and I was curious how to work out the odds.

So for example there are 4 people, 
Person A rights down a number between 1 and 4, For this example say number 1.
then person B chooses a number, for this example 4 so they are safe (if they choose  the written down number eg 1 they would need to do the chore)
then Person C Chooses a number from the remaining number, for this example 1, 2, 3, they choose 3
then Person D Chooses a number from the remaining number, for this example 1 or 2 they choose 2
Therefore Person A is only left to choose 1 thus they need to do the chore.

At the time of choosing I know the odds of Person B choosing a safe number 3/4, Person C's odds are 2/3, Person D's odds are 1/2, Person A's odds are 1/1, but Person A has 3 chances where somebody could pick the number (1) and therefore the would not need to choose and thus no chore.

Taking both factors into account what are the odds of choosing a safe number for each person?

Are you better to choose first or last?

Comment: The naive and correct answer is that all of them have an equal chance of having to do the chore, $\frac14$, making their probability of not having to do it ("choosing a safe number") $\frac34$.  It is rather like drawing the short straw

Comment: I guess you can rephrase the question and explain the process a bit better: One of the people (call her $Y$) writes down an integer from 1 to 4. We call this number $X$. Then, sequentially, each person apart from $Y$ chooses a number at random from the numbers that previous people have not chosen. $Y$ gets assigned the remaining number. There are 4 people and 4 numbers, so at the end of the process each number is assigned to exactly one person. The person who has number $X$ has to do the chores.

Is this correct?

I agree with @Henry on the solution. You can try to do this formally also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the reduction of the total cards (pool) make no difference to the probability that I will get a certain card in my hand](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394729/why-does-the-reduction-of-the-total-cards-pool-make-no-difference-to-the-proba)

Answer (score 0):

It is always helpful to alter your thinking a bit when the question seems a bit vague. All possibilities can be translated to arrangements of a sequence composed of $(1,2,3,4)$ without repetition. Without loss of generality, let us assume that $A$ initially picks the number $1$.

Let the total number of permutations be equal to $N=4!$

Notice that the number of sequences which end with $1$ is equal to $n=3!$

Hence the probability of having to do the chores is $P=
\frac nN=\frac {3!}{4!}=\frac 14$